# How to create a FileTable in SQL Server LocalDb?

Tags: sql-server, localdb, filetable, sql-server-2016-localdb

I installed SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDb alongside Visual Studio 2017. Googling "creating a FileTable" leads me to [Enable the Prerequisites for FileTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/enable-the-prerequisites-for-filetable) which needs [Enabling and configuring FILESTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/enable-and-configure-filestream).

It says:

> In the SQL Server Configuration Manager snap-in, locate the instance of SQL Server on which you want to enable FILESTREAM.

There I stopped: I can't find any SQL Server Configuration Manager on my PC. Now the question: how to create a FileTable in SQL Server LocalDb? Is it possible to enable and configure it only with queries?

PS: you can see in [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016#Programmability) that Express edition supports FileTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localdb does not support filetables due to security restrictions